# Qt GUI app works on my PC, but not another?

Tags: c++, qt

I've built my first c++ GUI app with the standalone version of Qt (mingw) and is works fine. I tried it on another computer, and it immediately crushes with Visual c++ runtime library error.

I actually tested copying the whole bin folder to the other PC and running the app from there, still the same.
What could cause the problem?

Additional Details:

I installed Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable, and I copied d3dcompiler_XX.dll too.
I got all the dll's from Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin.

I didn't link anything, and I have zero experience with linking in general.
I read several posts about this and they offered no solution, or a solution I cound not understand. Debug mode does this too. On my PC it runs outside the Qt Creator too.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23658

Comment: @Blood I've read this before, and the first step says enter: cd C:\path\to\Qt configure -static well there is no program named configure inside Qt's folder so this is an invalid command. Windows thinks that too. I can't even get past the first step.

Comment: Bit first of all - you want to build Qt static or dynamic?

Comment: @Blood I'd like it to be static, but If I get a dinamic version to work that's ok too.

Comment: Debug build is for developers, and therefore for developer PCs. Release build can be released to other PCs. E.g. the Visual Studio 2010 Redistributable only works with release builds.

Comment: Have you used Dependency Walker _on the other machine_ to check for missing DLLs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt 5.0 program runs in QtCreator but not outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566037/qt-5-0-program-runs-in-qtcreator-but-not-outside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the MinGW version to work after all, even tough I followed the documentation on deploying step by step, but I do have a working app now.

The problem's source was that some of the dlls from the Qt folder where registered and the program reached them even tough it wasn't at the same folder. I think the MinGW version needs more dlls compared to what's mentioned in the documentation, or it might be just my PC.

Here is what I did:

**1,** Downloaded the Qt creator with the Visual Studio complier, deleted everything except the source and rebuild the project.

**2,** Added this to the beginning of the project file:

```
QMAKE_LFAGS += -Wl,--repath=\\\$\$ORIGIN
QMAKE_LFAGS += -Wl,--repath=\\\$\$ORIGIN/lib
QMAKE_LFAGS += -Wl,--repath=\\\$\$ORIGIN/libs
QMAKE_RPATH=
```

this is supposed to make the app look for the dlls in . , ./lib, ./libs, but I think it does nothing, because the app won't find them in the lib folder.

**3,** Copied these dlls in the same folder: (same as the documentation)

```
D3DCompiler_43
icudt49
icuin49
icuuc49
libEGL
libGLESv2
Qt5Core
Qt5Gui
Qt5Widgets
Platforms (folder) containing qminimal and qwindows
msvcr100 and msvcp100
```

The minGW version would need LIBSTDC++-6, LIBGCC_S_DW2-1 and MINGWM10, but even with these it doesn't work for me.

**General Tips:**

- Note that while the mingw drops an error if one of these are not found, the VS version does nothing (immediately terminates without any message.)
- The most comfortable solution of testing the dependences is renaming the Qt folder, so that your app will not find it, this way you don't need a second computer to test it, nor unistalling the app like the documentation suggests.
- If you still have problems you can solve this the brute force way, like I did, by making a copy of the Qt folder, and deleting the elements one by one in the original one, to see what your program depends on. Unfortunately even the dependency checker does not mention some of them.

I wish you all happy coding, and more successful troubleshooting with this post.

Answer (score 1):

If your Qt-App is built dynamically with MinGW (i.e. using dynamic libraries), you need dlls from MinGW, (something like libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, etc). Locate these files at your MinGW installation directory. (May be your Qt installation)

Check "Application Dependencies" from [Deploy an application on window](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html)