# Qt created application not running without Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I'm trying to run my application(.exe) directly from debug folder by copying it in another system,but it is showing the following errors:

The program can't start because Qt5 Widgets.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I searched for the given .dll but couldn't find it anywhere.
Any Idea or suggestions.

Comment: You need to copy them from your Qt folder. Try to search by filename.

Comment: It is a typical and frequently asked question, you should have done some searching...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566037/qt-5-0-program-runs-in-qtcreator-but-not-outside/15567129#15567129
All dlls you need are part of the Qt framework, they are on your PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place Qt library dlls to right folders. In short, most dlls should be placed in the  folder of your executable, but plugins should be placed in subfolders, most of them in the subfolder `plugins`. Also you may need to place some compiler specific libraries with your executable too.
[Here is the link to Qt documentation for app distribution](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html)

Comment: That's really something Qt should be working on. This is such a burden to make your app "standalone" that it has drawn me away from some devs with Qt just for that.

Comment: @xgbi - ironically, as bad as Qt deployment is on desktop platforms, for android you get a neat single apk with all the dependencies in, it is still dynamic binding, but in a nice single package.