# Make exe file in QT-C++ missing qt5cored dll

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, nsis, qmake

When I copy project folder - was build and generate to bin folder - from my computer to anothers. It show *"The program can't start because QT5core.dll is missing"*.

Will I install *QT* to another computer for get all of *QT dll* - It arround 2gb. I think it's not good solution. Because when I want to transfer it to customer. He will not like to install this software for just seeing program.

I tried to use *NSIS* but I don't know how to get *dll* from my machine. And what *dll* will I need for move to build folder.

Thanks for any solution from you.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html), it explains how you should deploy your Qt application on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry ,I will check it right now.Thanks brother

Comment: Excuse me,When I use "nmake" , It show 'nmake' is not recognized. P/s: I use win7

Comment: make it, if you are using it in Linux. Use nmake if you are using it in Windows with MSVC, or mingw32-make if you are using the Qt SDK for Windows without MSVC. Is it right?

Comment: NMake is for MSVC on Windows, right. If you want to call it without adding the full path, you should do `call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%vsvarsall.bat"` (Visual Studio 2010), then do `nmake`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Ah, About my question : "Make exe file in QT-C++ missing qt5cored dll". Do you have any idea?

Comment: By the way, first, do not compile in ``Debug Mode``. When deploying QT-Apps one will likely build the executable in ``Release Mode``. Second, you can then add the requested dll files just by simply copying QtCore5.dll to the same directory as your executable.

Comment: Thanks for your sugesstion. There are dll files which I copy to release folder - It contain excute file. 

`Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
icudt51.dll
icuin51.dll
icuuc51.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll`

So, I have another question. What will we do if we want to `move these dll to another folder such as lib folder`. I think that it will be `clearly` if we move these dll to a clearly name folder . It also we will not hold on it at release folder.

Comment: Will I must copy `these dll` – I comment above – (in C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin) to `RELEASE` folder?
I cant’ copy them to `another folder` such as `\MyProject\Myresources\Mylib` folder?

Comment: When I copy to target machine. It show
`This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way Please contact the application’s support team for more information`
May you explain it for me. I’m looking forward to receiving your msg.

Comment: windeployqt.exe

Answer (score 1):

May be your required dependencies not installed on target machine, do as following answer, it gets solved:

[Qt 5.0 program runs in QtCreator but not outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15569097/1789729)

Comment: Dear Reza,I got `"Dependency walker shows IESHIMS.dll"` problem, I copy `IESHIMS.DLL` to `C:\\Program Files\ Internet Explorer` and `C\Windowns\System32` and release folder too. But it still get this warning when I use `Dependency Walker`

Comment: Its not main problem, but copy that file to app directory.

Comment: Hi Reza, I downgrade from Qt 5.10 to 4.8. Config something and it work fine now. :).

Comment: By the way, I think that it's not work fine with qt 5.10. It depend many dll thing. When I work with dll of Qt 4.0. It work fine and don't see any issues. That's sound great.

Comment: At qt 4.8. I got a problem that it didn't support for setCurrentText for combobox. Have you ever see it before. I design and code at qt5.0. It work fine. But when I use this project at QT.4.8. It didn't support for qt 4.8

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install anything on the other computer. Just try going to the location where your Qt application is installed and then navigate to "..\Qt\mingw53_32\bin" directory. The search for the missing .dll files, copy them to the location where your .exe file is situated and then re-run the application.