# qt compiles successfully but runs fail

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, mingw32, bitcoin

I compiled bitoin-qt,PTS coin and other Altercoins successfully ,but thay all can't running.
I use MinGW4.4 ,QT 4.8.5 download from website and QT creator 2.8.1.
This is my .pro setting:

```
BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mgw44-mt-s-1_53
BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/boost_1_53_0
BOOST_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib
BDB_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
BDB_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/openssl-1.0.1e/include
OPENSSL_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/openssl-1.0.1e
MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs
MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH=D:/C/coin/namecoinq/libs/miniupnpc-1.8
```

And I uncommented this code because MinGW4.4 doesn't suport it(I've used MinGW 4.6,4.7,4.8,but they all even compiled failed) :

```
#win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat
```

These all compiled by MinGW4.4 succefully,but the debug and release exe compiled both can't run.I have coped the qt dlls to the exe direction.When I debugged it,it broke before entering the main source.

**======================UPDATE edit==========================**

I know it's because of leveldb,but I don't know what's wrong with my compiling leveldb: 
    `TARGET_OS=NATIVE_WINDOWS mingw32-make libleveldb.a libmemenv.a`

When I use another altercoin leveldb source code,the error solves.But I use back to the original leveldb source code,the program breaks again.

Comment: What errors show up, if there are any?

Comment: `x-qt.exe has stopped working.A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.Please close the program`. and qt console says:`D:\down\P-rotoShares-psforkinit\build-protoshares-qt-44-Debug\debug\protoshares-qt.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.`

Comment: As others wrote, dependency walker is a useful tool for detecting dependency related issues for dlls. What does it say to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still seems to me you are missing a .dll. Try using dependency walker and verify you are not missing any dependencies.

Comment: Yes,you are right.It says:`Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.` But I copied all the dlls it mentioned,the warning message still appear.And my exe program breakes more quickly.

Comment: Maybe this information helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566037/qt-5-0-program-runs-in-qtcreator-but-not-outside

Comment: This should have been a comment I believe once you gain enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I write log to debug it and find it breaks at:`pblocktree = new CBlockTreeDB(nBlockTreeDBCache, false, fReindex);` And can't enter CBlockTreeDB