# qt 5.2.0 windows 7 missing dlls (program crashes)

Tags: windows, qt, qt5, mingw32

Trying to run a Windows 7, Qt 5.2.0 program and it crashes immediately.
I have the mingw48_32 version, and 32 bit version of Qt 5.2.0.
I dont have Visual Studio, although I did download and install some of the
2010 VS SDK and .Net framework stuff, still no luck.
Ive tried searching for these things to no avail.  If it is somewhere on my machine
I have yet to find them.

After running dependency walker it shows the following missing DLL's:

```
GPSVC.DLL
IESHIM.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-INTERLOCKED-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
```

I really appreciate any help on getting past this!  Already spent a couple days
trying to figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: On another computer I seem to have found all of the API-MS-WIN stuff in a directory under 'Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft-windows-minkernelapinamespace_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22125_none_blahblahblah'  Anyone know what this is or where I can download it online?  Must be some SDK Im missing?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I've run into the same problem, but the only information I can find seems to indicate that the "API-MS-WIN-*.DLL" are Windows 8 DLLs. I'm not sure why Qt would produce an executable that depends on them if I'm building on Windows 7...

Comment: read this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15569097/1789729

Comment: Those are WinRT DLLs which don't exist on Win 7

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me today. I found the problem. My program was loading a DLL with wrong version. This can occur when from the PATH or in the folder of the program is found incompatible library, which have references to these "missing" libraries. In the documentation of Windows is explained in what priority folders are searched for DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I realized that I have been copy the wrong dll files. They had the same name that the old version (qt 5.0 to qt 5.5.1). So, I just copy the right files and was done.

Answer (score 0):

If qt project depends on multimedia plugin:

in .pro file add
`win32: QTPLUGIN.audio=qtaudio_windows`

Answer (score -2):

I get similar errors when I compile a C++ program under Windows 10 with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and try to install it under Windows 7. **The solution**: compile the C++ program under Windows 7.