# Application doesnot launch created using MSVC2010

Tags: exe, qt5, visual-studio-2010

I have created a exe using qt 5.0.2. Application launches if I try o launch it using qt creator. However application fail to launch which is created using MSVC  2010 pro edition.
When I double click on exe it will comes out and it will not display any error or dll missing errors. Is there any way to fix/debug these kind of issues.

Comment: application comes out when I click on exe. I tried chmod 777 exe_name. It did not helped me

Comment: When I narrow down the problem,  my issue looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702879/exe-file-does-not-run-without-qtcreator. However it did not solve my problem. Thanks for this post.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28766  This is a bug in QT 5.0.2. Its in unresolved sate

Comment: Its discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537651/qtcreator-exe-does-work-fine-inside-qtcreator-but-doesnt-outside

Comment: Very useful link http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23658. It works now..!  Problem SOLVED. Thank you