# I am not being able to open my Qt exe. file outside of Qt's IDE

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am developing a program using Qt and it is opened normally whenever I open it from Qt's IDE, though when I try to open it directly from the exe file in the debug folder it simply requests a lot of dlls and even if I download all dlls requested.

I already have VC++ installed.

The error I am getting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWJmc.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [qtcreator - exe does work fine inside qtcreator but doesn't outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537651/qtcreator-exe-does-work-fine-inside-qtcreator-but-doesnt-outside)

Comment: You have missing dependent dlls.

Comment: Don't download dlls ! They already are in your Qt install folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools I just want to mention that can be helpful here. The first tool is [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) that can help identify the missing DLLs, the dll versions that are being used, and the path to the dlls. The other tool is provided by Qt called [WindeployQt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) which copies all the Qt dependencies in your application to your executable path.